# VB Express 2010 Could not find a file I no longer want to find

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, publish

I had copied these files into my **My Project** directory of my project to reference them as a assembly, but I no longer want them in that directory as when I publish my project I get a set of warnings that say that these assemblies were incorrectly specified as a file.

How can I get rid of these errors?

```
Error   4   Could not find file 'My Project\DotNetOpenAuth.dll'.    MiPro
Error   5   Could not find file 'My Project\GDrive.Explorer.exe'.   MiPro
Error   6   Could not find file 'My Project\GDrive.Framework.dll'.  MiPro
Error   7   Could not find file 'My Project\Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.dll'. MiPro
Error   9   Could not find file 'My Project\Google.Apis.dll'.   MiPro
Error   8   Could not find file 'My Project\Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll'.  MiPro
Error   21  Could not find file 'My Project\log4net.dll'.   MiPro
Error   12  Could not find file 'My Project\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll'. MiPro
Error   10  Could not find file 'My Project\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll'.  MiPro
Error   11  Could not find file 'My Project\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll'.  MiPro
Error   13  Could not find file 'My Project\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'.   MiPro
Error   17  Could not find file 'My Project\System.Net.Http.dll'.   MiPro
Error   14  Could not find file 'My Project\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll'.    MiPro
Error   15  Could not find file 'My Project\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll'.    MiPro
Error   16  Could not find file 'My Project\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll'.    MiPro
Error   18  Could not find file 'My Project\System.Runtime.dll'.    MiPro
Error   19  Could not find file 'My Project\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'.    MiPro
Error   20  Could not find file 'My Project\Zlib.Portable.dll'. MiPro
Message 3   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'.  C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiPro\MiPro\app.config 23  43  MiPro
Message 2   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'version'.  C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiPro\MiPro\app.config 23  28  MiPro
Message 1   Could not find schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime'.   C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MiPro\MiPro\app.config 23  11  MiPro
```

Also, I get an error which says `Application validation did not succeed.`

What are the possible reasons for it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Project Properties (Solution Explorer - a window at the extreme right or left of your screen; Right Click on the Top-Most directory: The project name; Select Properties)
2. Go to the Publish section
3. Select `Application Files` and just exclude the files you don't want and you should good to go.

If anyone has a better and a more descriptive solution, please upload it. I'll accept it.